# Hide globals in Flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I am writing some code in JavaScript + Flow and would like to keep it as pure as possible, which also means skipping globals such as `window` or `document`, passing those as function arguments. But it’s quite easy to forget a stray `document` reference here or there. Is it possible to ban those globals somehow, allowing them only in the top-level file? So far I am doing this at the top of most of my documents:

```
const window = undefined
const document = undefined
```

This way only instances passed in as arguments work:

```
// This works
function foo(document: Document) {
    document.doThisOrThat();
}

// This triggers a typecheck error 
function bar() {
    document.doThisOrThat();
}
```

Are there other solutions? (I would love a whitelist approach, disallowing all globals except those whitelisted.)

Answer (score 0):

You can set Flow to ignore the flowlibs by adding `no_flowlib=true` in the `[options]` section of the flowconfig.

From there, you can make your own libs folder and only include the library definitions you want. To make them globally available, add the path to your libs folder in the `[libs]` section of your flowconfig.